# How can I export a group of settings in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, configuration

Drupal 8 has this new configuration management tool at `/admin/config/development/configuration`. I have an experimental site running Drupal 8 beta14, and I want to import a few settings into my new beta15 site. I don't want to copy everything, I experimented with various things on the old site and only need a few things on the new one.

What I want to copy are content types, the fields in those content types as well as image styles. But looking at the export tool, it seems I can only export a single item at a time.

Is there a way to export all items of a specific group at once, e.g. all content types or all image styles? And for content types, is there a way to export all the fields as well together with the content type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting fields for content type](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190241/exporting-fields-for-content-type)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I export and import content types (including fields) between environments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274955/how-do-i-export-and-import-content-types-including-fields-between-environments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different things you can do.

You can, as you found, export and import single objects.

Or, you can do a config sync. Which means everything and is usually used to import configuration changes from staging to production or similar.

So you can do a full config export, then all the files will be in your staging folder (not the same as a staging environment) and import them in a different site. Note that there are some limitations, for example, you always need to do a full import (so export the existing config of a site, update it with some changes, then import it again) and the sync only works if the UUID in system.site matches, as it is not supported to import from a separate installation. (But you can import a group of files that don't exist yet.. careful with the UUID's, as the same object with a different UUID is treated as a delete + create, not update).

So you need to pick the files you want to re-use and put them either into an existing export from the target site or put them in a config/install folder of a module, then it will be imported when that module is installed (and *only* then, there are no automated updates).

You can also look at the 8.x version of the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) project, which basically offers a UI to pick a number of configuration files, similar to what you might know from D7.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is currently supported. The best candidate for that would be Drush, and its `config-export` command. But as you can see below, there's no indication that groups are supported.

```
$ drush config-export --help
Export config from the active directory.

Examples:
 drush config-export --skip-modules=devel  Export configuration; do not include the devel module in the exported configuration, 
                                           regardless of whether or not it is enabled in the site.

Arguments:
 label                                     A config directory label (i.e. a key in $config_directories array in settings.php). Defaults 
                                           to 'staging'

Options:
 --add                                     Run `git add -p` after exporting. This lets you choose which config changes to stage for      
                                           commit.                                                                                       
 --branch=<branchname>                     Make commit on provided working branch. Ignored if used without --commit or --push.           
 --commit                                  Run `git add -A` and `git commit` after exporting.  This commits everything that was exported 
                                           without prompting.                                                                            
 --destination                             An arbitrary directory that should receive the exported files. An alternative to label        
                                           argument                                                                                      
 --message                                 Commit comment for the exported configuration.  Optional; may only be used with --commit or   
                                           --push.                                                                                       
 --push                                    Run `git push` after committing.  Implies --commit.                                           
 --remote=<origin>                         The remote git branch to use to push changes.  Defaults to "origin".                          
 --skip-modules                            A list of modules to ignore during export (e.g. to avoid listing dev-only modules in exported 
                                           configuration).

Aliases: cex
```

My best bet at this point would be to file an issue against the [Drush project](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues) so that you submit a feature request. I agree with you it'd make sense because currently it's pretty painful not to miss dependencies.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've filed https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1601

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Config partial export](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_partial_export) module which allows you to exports only the selected files from the list of modified config files. It is able to export to a tarball only modified configuration files. After export you can copy the files from the tarball to your config/install folder in order to add them to your install profile and apply those changes on next install.

The module adds *Partial config* tab to *Configuration management*. It also provides a new drush command (see: `drush cpex --help` for help).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module for grouping configurations which is not stable yet for D8 or checkout [Drupal Console](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-export-content-type.html)

Take a look at this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/190242/23477

Comment: if the same answer fits two questions, please vote to close as possible duplicate. If it's only similar, then please post it directly, with needed alterations.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Python script which exports **a group of configuration items** using `drush`. You can find the script on a related thread, [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/226484/68611).