# Having multiple active config splits causes main configuration directory to be ignored

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to have a config setup for a multisite, so that I have following config directories:

- `default` - common config
- `dev` - split for dev environment
- `local` - split for local environment
- `<site>` - split for a site

When I'm working on a local copy of the site, this means I have `local` and `<site>` [splits](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) active at the same time. I've experienced, that all the configuration apart from that blaclisted in `local` was then exported (when running `drush cex`) to the `<site>` split, so `default` directory is empty. How can I override this behavior, so that `<site>` split would contain only specified graylisted configuration?

Comment: `drush csex <site>` maybe?

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, it looks like it works, after I manually moved the config to the `default` config directory. I still would like to know, if there's any automated solution using ordinary `cex`.

Comment: Not sure . For me this setup seems to be a bit error-prone. I prefer each site having its completely own config and syncing shared features with the Features module during development. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297630/15055

Comment: Hmm, I evaluated features module as an alternative, but abandoned the idea, because `config_split` seems to be much more used solution, so I expected better support possibilities.