# Is there any way to capture only the updates from "drush cex"?

Tags: drush

I did a cex to "reset" my config being exported. I then made a bunch of changes to a bundle. Now when I do a new cex I see only the yml files containing my most recent changes. Is there any way to capture JUST these files (into a new folder)?

If I specify a --destination; it dumps my entire config there. Not what I want.

Comment: perhaps if you just make sure your using version control such as git then after you export run a git diff to get the files that have changed  as you cant use the --destination flag to export only updated files you would need  to make some  custom dev for that.

Comment: You may want to look into the [Features module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) or [Config split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split). Depending on what you're doing you could alternatively use some git tricks to copy the files to a new directory or even just export them individually through the config management UI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I export and import content types (including fields) between environments?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274955/how-do-i-export-and-import-content-types-including-fields-between-environments)

Comment: @sonfd, i had used Features a while back (in D8, used it 100s of time in D7) and it seemed to make a mess with auto including all sorts of dependencies. In D7 it was much easier to select just what was wanted. I'll take another look.. maybe they have improved this. Not sure how Config Split would work here as it isn't able to grab config with that sort of resolution. Other answers are mostly the same... basically use git to manage. I wasn't sure how that would help, but came up with this: git diff --name-only | xargs cp -t myExportFolder  - which does what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Config partial export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_partial_export)

> It is able to export to a tarball only modified configuration files.

For available commands in drush:

```
drush cpex --help
```

Comment: I had looked briefly at this last night but didn't think it would really help; but reading again perhaps it might be useful. If it is basically able to grab specific files. Sadly i was hoping for something that just listed the new ones - as that would be everything i need.